# Convergence of series. Revision for exam.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am new to the community so hopefully I still manage to follow the basic principles and rules around here. I am studying for the real analysis exam that is scheduled for friday and big was my surprise when I got stuck with the following problem.

Inspect the convergence of the following series:

$$ 1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n^2+1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^{n^{2}}$$
$$ 2) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{((-1)^{n}+1)n}{n^2-n+1}$$

To solve the first one I tried Cauchy's criterion and for the second one I tried to divide them into two addents and then inspect their convergence but all my attempts to use mythese ideas have faced failure. It feels stupid to be stuck with easy looking problems for three hours so I hope that someone here can make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Have u tried ratio test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example, you can use the root test. Since,
$$
\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \frac{1}{e^2} < 1,
$$
you conclude that the series is convergent.

For the second example, you can just note that, since odd terms are zero,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{((-1)^n+1)n}{n^2-n+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{2k}{(2k)^2-2k+1},
$$

which is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer :) I have two questions. First one is that how can i show that the limit exists without using Laurent series (it's pretty obvious by that but we have not learned them yet)… The other question is that how can I compare the second result with harmonic series (we have proved that harmonic series diverge but how can I use the info correctly? Is the < and Weierstrass appropriate way to do that?)

Comment: @Godizzer Regarding the limit, you can write it as $\lim e^{\ln (\cdots)} = e^{\lim \ln (\cdots)}$ and use L'Hopital's rule. Regarding the comparison I meant that under certain conditions, if $\lim a_n / b_n$ is finite and nonzero, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ have the same nature (both convergent or both divergent).